# create pppoe connection in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am writing an app that allows creation of pppoe in windows phone 7.goal is to be able to dial a connection with given username/password over wireless.

t what API I shall use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with PPPoE but, given the name, you'll probably need to use raw sockets.

Take a look at [Network and Web Services Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637518%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to see what options are available to you. Then you'll probably need to look at [Sockets for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202870%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and the related [System.Net.Sockets reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there support for raw sockets in wp7?

Comment: Sockets? Yes. ICMP packets? No.